# Сколько предикативных единиц в этом предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

> Труд составляет самую крепкую и надежную связь между тем человеком,
>   который трудится, и тем обществом, на пользу которого направлен этот
>   труд.

Здесь сложноподчиненное предложение, скорее всего с несколькими придаточными.

Comment: Скорее всего с несколькими придаточными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Труд составляет самую крепкую и надежную связь между тем ***человеком***, **который трудится**, и тем ***обществом***, **на пользу которого направлен этот труд**.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с двумя неоднородными определительными придаточными, которые относятся к разным опорным существительным "человеком" и "обществом". В нем три предикативные единицы: (1) труд составляет связь (составное именное сказуемое), (2) который трудится,  (3)направлен труд.

Главное предложение: Труд составляет самую крепкую и надежную связь **между** тем **человеком** и тем **обществом**, союз И связывает однородные дополнения "между человеком и "обществом", к ним относятся указательные слова ТЕМ.

Для связи придаточных используются союзные слова (1) КОТОРЫЙ и (2) КОТОРОГО,  в придаточных предложениях они играют роль (1) подлежащего и (2) дополнения.

Comment: В схеме исправить: (1) "составляет связь" - это сказуемое,  (2) направлен - это сказуемое,  КОТОРОГО - это дополнение.  Связь (какую) - между человеком и обществом - это однородные несогласованные определения.